# Where is the 'lms.env.json' file?

Tags: openedx

I'm configuring open edx. But where can I find the lms.env.json and cams.env.json files? I installed open edx and it works now. But where are those two files? I need to edit them to configure edx according to the tutorial

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your installation, 
But mostly for Production, Native installation, Destack etc installations.

```
/edx/app/edxapp/lms.(lms/cms).json
```

[image]

Comment: I can confirm, I did find it under /edx/app/edxapp/